# Creating email task to Google App Engine Task Queue (using PHP)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, email, pdf, task-queue

I'm a newbie to Google App Engine Task Queue and would appreciate if someone could give me a simple tutorial I can follow to achieve my goal.

I currently have a GAE site which I am able to grab inputted data from a form and output into a pdf file (using fpdf). I have been using PHPMailer to then attach this pdf to an email message to be sent out. Problem is, it locks up the page until the file is sent out, which can take up to 15 seconds (or times out if longer).

I believe task queue in GAE can achieve this without the lockup. Problem is, as a beginner, trying to read the GAE site about task queue is not simple.

Is anyone able to give detailed steps on using task queue in PHP e.g what code to use and where exactly to put it? Currently I have 'proposal.php' which has the form then submits to 'proposal-thank-you.php which executes the following code:

- stores data into CloudSQL DB
- produces the PDF file using the data submitted
- emails the PDF as an attachment using PHPMailer
- Spits out a thank message on the page

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/taskqueue/overview-push should be a good starting point. Concretely, you'd most probably want to create a separate PHP script and handler, say /email, and put all the long lasting work, e.g. making PDF & emailing, there. From you proposal-thank-you.php, you'll then create a PushTask pointing at /email and pass the data form data through the $query_data argument.